Не работает аутентификация на хостинге DRF JWT
Сделал бэк проекта на Django rest, все протестировал, все работает хорошо, решил его залить на хостинг, все работает кроме аутентификации, как бы я не пытался передать токен всегда получаю:
{
"detail": "Учетные данные не были предоставлены."
}
вот я получаю токен:

вот я его применяю к запросу:

и чтобы я не делал все равно получаю "Учетные данные не были предоставлены.".
Что я попробовал сделать чтобы исправить это:

CORS разрешил для всех хостов: CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
проверил пользователя, он есть, он активен, права на создания проекта у него тоже есть
версии питона, модулей локально и на хостинге одинаковы

опять же повторюсь, локально такой проблемы нет, вот скриншот:


Проверь, настроил ли ты CORS в middleware. MIDDLEWARE = [
...,
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...
]
